# Existing tool to push a complex JSON into Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra

I have a complex JSON document as an input, that contains a lot of fields, nested fields, arrays, etc.
and I want to push directly this JSON document into my Cassandra table, in order to avoid to be obliged to write a custom code to do a simple mapping (that can change over time).

Does a generic tool exist to do this ?

Important assumptions :

- The fields names in the JSON document can be unique across the document, to make it easier.
- The nesting level of each field in the JSON document is not necessarily the same than the one in the Cassandra table

**Examples**

JSON document extract :

```
"userID": "john.doe@gmail.com",
"isReg": true,
"infos": {
    "countryIds": [
        {
            "id": 111,
            "country": "UK"
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "country": "France"
        },
        {
            "id": 333,
            "country": "Sweden"
        },
        {
            "id": 444,
            "country": "Germany"
        }
    ],
    "pseudo": "abc12345",
    "name": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
    }, (...)
```

Cassandra table

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS country_id (
    id int,
    country text
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS name (
    first_name text,
    last_name text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(  
    user_id text,
    is_reg boolean,
    country_ids SET<FROZEN<country_id>>,
    pseudo text,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an out-of-the-box solution for this and it will require custom code to achieve what you need.

If you are able to publish the data to Kafka, you can map the fields to CQL columns and push them to Cassandra as a sink using the **[DataStax Kafka Connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/)**. Cheers!